# php - split string after by special character after specific occurence

Tags: php, string

i want to break a sentence after every 3rd `.`

example string:

```
$var = "ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.";
```

expected result:

```
[0] = ABC. ABC. ABC

[1] = ABC. ABC. ABC

[2] = ABC. ABC.
```

Comment: And is it "after the 3rd period" (leaving the period behind, as your text says) or "on the third period" (deleting the period, as your expected result shows)?

Comment: We do not provide from scratch code here on SO.  Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use the `explode()` function and then add  them back together. Something like this:

```
$line = "ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.";
$tempSplit = explode(".", $line);

$result;
for ($x = 0; $x < count($tempSplit); $x++)
{
    $result[intval($x / 3)] .= $tempSplit[$x] . ".";
}
```

Then you'll have to figure out if you want the final `.` to stay or not. you can remove it with the `substr()` function: [link](http://php.net/substr).

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var = "ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.";
$array=explode(".", $var);
$str="";
$count=0;
$arr="";
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++){
    $str[]=$array[$i];

    $count++;
    if($count>2){
        $arr[$i]=implode(". ",$str);
        $str="";
        $count=0;

    }

}
var_dump(array_values($arr));
```

Output will be

```
 array (size=3)
  0 => string 'ABC. ABC. ABC' (length=13)
  1 => string 'ABC. ABC. ABC' (length=13)
  2 => string 'ABC. ABC. ' (length=10)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this:

```
$test = "ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.ABC.\n"
      . "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\n"
      . "Lorem ipsizzle dolizzle you son of a bizzle amizzle, \n"
      . "its fo rizzle adipiscing elit. The bizzle tellivizzle \n"
      . "velizzle, gizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle bow wow wow, \n"
      . "owned vizzle, owned. Pellentesque bow wow wow tortor. \n"
      . "Sizzle erizzle. Shizznit izzle dolor dapibus get down \n"
      . "get down tempizzle yo. Maurizzle go to hizzle bizzle \n"
      . "izzle. Da bomb izzle dawg. Pellentesque eleifend \n"
      . "rhoncus dope. In sure break yo neck, yall shiz \n"
      . "dictumst. Shiznit dapibus. Curabitizzle boom \n"
      . "shackalack fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah \n"
      . "home g-dizzle, pretizzle rizzle, mattizzle crackalackin, \n"
      . "eleifend funky fresh, nunc. Shit suscipizzle. Integizzle \n"
      . "sempizzle velit sed daahng dawg.";

$result = preg_split("%((?:[^\.]*?\.){3})%s", $test, -1,
          PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY + PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

echo "<pre>"; print_r ($result); echo "</pre>";
```

If it's really about sentences, they usually end with a full stop ("."), followed by a space (" "). To avoid these spaces in your result you may use the following regular expression:

```
$result = preg_split("%((?:[^\.]*?\.\s?){3})%s", $test, -1,
          PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY + PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```